# Split dataset into training and test by month

Tags: python, neural-network, training-data, test-data

I was not able to find the answer to this anywhere. I have data for three months, where I would like to split it into the first two months('Jan-19', 'Feb-19') as training set and the last month as the test ('Mar-19').

Previously I have done random sampling with simple code like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=109)
```

and before that assigned y as the label and x as the columns to use to predict. I'm not sure how to assign the test and training to the months I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in a pandas dataframe, you can use subsetting like this:

```
X_train = X[X['month'] != 'Mar-19']
y_train = y[X['month'] != 'Mar-19']

X_test = X[X['month'] == 'Mar-19']
y_test = y[X['month'] == 'Mar-19']
```

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one here solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You try this option and see if it helps.

```
dataset_train = df['2004-02-12 11:02:39':'2004-02-13 23:52:39']
dataset_test = df['2004-02-13 23:52:39':]
```